# Json Deserialise not consistent with apparently identical data

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm deserialising a `Newtonsoft` `JArray` to a `.NET` `DataTable` using:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataSet.ToString(), typeof(DataTable));
```

Where `dataSet` is a `JArray` of the basic array format:

```
{
  "dataset": [
    {          
      "periodDesc": "2020",     
      "cstCode": "",    
      "CIFValue": null
    },
    {
      "periodDesc": "2017",   
      "cstCode": "",   
      "CIFValue": null      
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I get this dataset from an API call via a `JObject` and it works fine:

```
JObject jObject = GetJsonFromWebRequest(url);
JArray jArray = (JArray)jObject["dataset"];
```

Now to do some testing, I took the json response from the `GetJsonFromWebRequest` and saved it to a `.json` file.

I also did the same with the `JArray` when I encountered problems; Whether I use the whole response and parse to a JObject first, or whether I use the subset JArray, when I load this data from file, it just doesn't work! I get the error:

> "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> 'System.Data.DataTable' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
> {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error
> either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or
> change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a
> collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
> be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
> added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON
> array."

I'm assuming this might have something to do with linebreaks or something, or how I've saved it as `.JSON` instead of `.TXT` maybe?! But I have no idea what is going on - looking at the objects while debugging they seem **absolutely identical** and it is successfully parsing the `JArray` as a `JArray` - it's just the `Deserialize` bit that fails.

Any idea what's going on here?!

Here are the contents of the file I'm loading from minus the help URL - the mock response:

```
{
  "validation": {
    "status": {
      "name": "Ok",
      "value": 0,
      "category": 0,
      "description": "",
      "helpUrl": "For more reference visit"
    },
    "message": null,
    "count": {
      "value": 5,
      "started": "2021-09-15T09:14:05.277794+02:00",
      "finished": "2021-09-15T09:14:07.8662927+02:00",
      "durationSeconds": 2.5884986999999997
    },
    "datasetTimer": {
      "started": "2021-09-15T09:14:05.277794+02:00",
      "finished": "2021-09-15T09:14:15.2487336+02:00",
      "durationSeconds": 9.9709396
    }
  },
  "dataset": [
    {
      "periodDesc": "2017",
      "cstCode": "",
      "CIFValue": null
    },
    {
      "periodDesc": "2018",
      "cstCode": "",
      "CIFValue": null
    },
    {
      "periodDesc": "2019",
      "cstCode": "",
      "CIFValue": null
    },
    {
      "periodDesc": "2020",
      "cstCode": "",
      "CIFValue": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: _"or how I've saved it as .JSON instead of .TXT maybe?!"_ - by the time the content of the file reaches the serializer, it has no idea whatsoever what the source of the JSON is, let alone the file extension.

Comment: Please show the file contents and how you are reading it and deserializing it.

Comment: Have you checked the character encoding?  For example - ASCII vs UTF8 vs UTF16

Comment: @Llama I've added the file that is the copy/paste of the response from the source.

Comment: [Example 1](https://rextester.com/TTI17297) (based on your initial code and JSON). [Example 2](https://rextester.com/DIZXAP45220) (based on your file JSON). At the moment my conclusion is that you must be doing something wrong outside of what you've shown us in your question.

Comment: @Llama I've just copy-pasted your 2nd example into a test and it doesn't work. I still get the same error. This must have something to do with the Unit Test environment?? But I don't see how!?

Comment: I figured it out, had to add NewtonSoft dependency in the test project so it was in parity with the API project version - there are behavioural differences around handling null values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was something to do with `NewtonSoft` version incompatibility. I needed to explicitly install `NewtonSoft` `3.x` in my `NUnit` test project and it works fine.

While the main API project doesn't have this package dependency / reference, it did have a line in the `startup`:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Which apparently does the same thing?!